# When to flag a question and when to vote for closing?

Tags: discussion, flagging, vote-to-close

So the question explains itself, since both have the same options, when is each one more appropriate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Voting to close](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) should be your go-to action when you see questions that are off topic, unclear or duplicates. [Flagging](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) should be used when a question needs moderator attention. This is used for spam, offensive posts or other situations where moderator intervention is needed.

*Flagging to close* allows lower rep users to bring questions that should be closed to the attention of higher rep users and moderators, who have the power to *vote to close*.

When a user [flags to close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177752/replace-close-flags-with-close-suggestions), it places the question in the review queue for high rep users and moderators alike. It does not show up as a moderator flag.

When a user with enough rep to vote to close should be voting to close, not flagging to close. Any flags to close by a user with more than 3000 rep, the [flag will automatically be converted to a vote to close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173520/flag-converted-into-close-vote).